# Есть ли аналоги normalize.css?

Tags: сss3

Интересует, есть ли что - нибудь новее чем normalize? Я вижу разработчик делал последний коммит больше полугода назад, а браузеры на месте не стоят. Я не против использовать normalize и дальше, но возможно есть более лучшее решение.

Answer (score 0):

Я не встречал лучшее решение для нормализации стилей в вебе. Как бы `normalize.css` сделан для того, чтобы максимально приблизить все браузеры к одному стандарту, как может. На протяжении пол года очевидно есть изменения, но вроде бы ничего такого, чтобы нужно было нормализовать